# Why does a function with an input that has a reference to a pointer not compile?

Tags: c++, c, avr

I've tested this on my Linux box, which has gcc, and compiles fine.

```
void myFunc(int* &input);
```

That compiles with no errors.

On my avr, declaring the same function:

```
void myFunc(int* &input);
```

Results in an compilation error:

```
expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
```

gcc version on linux is 4.6.3

gcc version for avr (avr-gcc) is 3.4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C (not sure about C++)

```
void myFunc(int* &input);
```

is not a valid declaration. **In C, all calls are by value**. There is no call by reference unlike C++.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration you are using is valid in C++ but invalid in C, since in C there are no references. You should use `g++` or another C++ compiler to compile the code.

```
void myFunc(int* &input);
```

By the way, this passes a pointer *by* reference, not a pointer to a reference. That is, the reference is to a pointer, not the other way around.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, looks like I had my file ext. called ".cpp" when I compiled it on Linux using gcc.

Comment: How do you run it? On my system GCC 4.7.3 gives the same error you get from avr-gcc.

Comment: gcc test.cpp -> no error | 

gcc test.c -> errors as expected

Answer (score 2):

Save this code with `.c` extension and compile. you will get same error.because C does not allow to use references in function parameter list, while declaration and definition As Like C++.

Comment: Yeah looks like I had .cpp as the extension instead of c while invoking gcc.